# upload both form and file using ajax in jquery validation plugin in php

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

These is my form

```
    <form action="<?php echo base_url();?> candidate/ajaxadd" name="candidate_form" method="post" id="candidate_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

These is ajax function in jquery validation plugin

```
    submitHandler: function(form) {
              var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
            $.ajax({
                url: form.action,
                type: form.method,
                data: formData,
                async: false,
                complete: dispaly_candidate,
                success: function(response) { alert(response);
                    if(response == "false"){
                        alert("Please enter all fields");
                    }
                },
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false            
            });
```

Comment: please format your code

Comment: Please 1. format your code 2. explain - what have you tried so far? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I do not understand the question at all.. That is not a form.. that is a form element.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand question but:

```
   submitHandler = function(form) {
                var formURL = form.attr("action");
                var formData = form[0];
                var formData = new FormData(formData);
                $.ajax({
                    url: formURL,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: formData,
                    mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function(data) {
                        var response=$.trim(data);
                        alert(response);
                        if(response === "false"){
                            alert("Please enter all fields");
                        }
                    }          
                });
             };
    // use finction:
    submitHandler($("#candidate_form"));
```

You need to ask the question in detail. And this function is a correction that (I guess) you're looking for.